# ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient UnSubscribe function hangs

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, publish-subscribe

I tried to use RedisPubSubServer but that won't work with key notifications because I need to subscribe channels specified by patterns. So I created my own solution:

```
public class RedisKeySubscriber
{
    public string Host { get; private set; }
    public int Port { get; private set; }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, IRedisSubscription> _subscriptions;

    public RedisKeySubscriber(string host, int port)
    {
        Host = host;
        Port = port;
        _subscriptions = new Dictionary<string, IRedisSubscription>();
    }

    public void Subscribe(string key, Action<string, string> handler)
    {
        lock (_subscriptions)
        {
            IRedisSubscription subscription;
            if (_subscriptions.TryGetValue(key, out subscription))
                return;

            // FIXME this might potentially create too many threads
            var client = new ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient(Host, Port);
            subscription = client.CreateSubscription();
            subscription.OnMessage = handler;
            _subscriptions.Add(key, subscription);
            new Thread(() => subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching(key)).Start();
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(string key)
    {
        lock (_subscriptions)
        {
            IRedisSubscription subscription;
            if (!_subscriptions.TryGetValue(key, out subscription))
                return;
            subscription.UnSubscribeFromChannelsMatching(key);
            _subscriptions.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    public void UnsubscribeAll()
    {
        lock (_subscriptions)
        {
            foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions)
                subscription.Value.UnSubscribeFromChannelsMatching(subscription.Key);
            _subscriptions.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UnsubscribeAll();
    }
}
```

I realized this hangs on PSUBSCRIBE command. Everything else works just fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an additional 'control' channel. So the handler is subscribed both to the channels matching 'key' and to a channel like 'CHCTRL:guid' where guid is a specific GUID created by the class instance. The unsubscribe function publish a message on CHCTRL:guid and the handler can understand it's time to unsubscribe itself because the message doesn't come from 'key'.

Alternative and suggested solution is to not use ServiceStack.Redis.